# Comment out/delete blocks in large amount of files

Tags: regex, sed, nagios

I'm attempting to write something that can process Nagios config files containing a block of text, and either add # to the start of each line, or delete the block. (To function as a kind of mass check removal in Nagios itself).

Ex:

```
define service {
        service_description     Service 1
        use                     Template 1
        host_name               Host 1
        check_command           Command A
}
define service {
        service_description     Service 2
        use                     Template 1
        host_name               Host 1
        check_command           Command B
}
define service {
        service_description     Service 3
        use                     Template 1
        host_name               Host 1
        check_command           Command C
}
```

Would need to change to this (or equivalent):

```
define service {
        service_description     Service 1
        use                     Template 1
        host_name               Host 1
        check_command           Command A
}
#define service {
#        service_description     Service 2
#        use                     Template 1
#        host_name               Host 1
#        check_command           Command B
#}
define service {
        service_description     Service 3
        use                     Template 1
        host_name               Host 1
        check_command           Command C
}
```

Is there a way to regex match the block between "define service {" and "}", and containing either "Service 2" or "Command "B", and append/delete the block via sed/awk/perl, etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes there is. Awk or perl would probably be easier to read than a sed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '
# take each paragraph one by one
/define service {/,/}/{
# inside paragraphe, add each line (one at a time) in buffer
   H
# if not the end of paragraphe, delete the line (from output) (and cycle to next line)
   /}/!d
# empty current line (the last of paragraphe) and swap with the whole buffer
   s/.*//;x
# if it contain Service2 (and Command B on next line) goto to label comm
   /Service2/ b comm
   /Command B/ b comm
# goto label head (so no Service2 nor command b in paragraphe)
   b head
:comm
# comment each line of paragraphe (multiline with \n as new line)
   s/\n/&#/g
: head
# remove first character (a new line due to use of H and not h on first line)
   s/.//
   }
# default behaviour that print the content
 ' YourFile
```

Self commented

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that creates the match you want:

```
/define service\s\{.*(Service 2|Command B).*\}/s
```

You can [test it here](https://regex101.com/r/nH6gW9/1). I have no experience with sed, awk or perl, so I will not make any attempt to create a replacement.

Comment: a bit quick as reply, missing the context, parameter and sed version to use. It will not work on posix sed and also not on GNU sed without specific option.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -n '/define service {/,/}/{:1;N;/\}/!b 1;/Command B\|Service 2/{s/\n/\n#/g;s/^/#/g;p;d;b 1};p;d;b 1}' file_name`
**This is how it works**
picks the block within braces;keeps appending to pattern space till a closing brace is found;searches the patter space for the two key words; if found then appends a # in front of every new line in pattern space and prints the content. Clears the pattern space and repeats the provess

Comment: This works great, thanks! Added a -i to the sed to write the change to each file in my find loop.

Comment: Upon testing, this also deletes any "define host {" blocks in the Nagios configs. Why is this?

Comment: @Myaá: Could you provide an example. I am not sure if I have understood the question rigth !